# In c# and entity framework how can I ensure that existing records cannot be changed and new records can only be added after passing checks?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, oop, accounting

I would like to create a simple general ledger app in c# 6 and entity framework 6 but I guess I am struggling with the proper design.

From my (simplified) point of view a general ledger is a collection of transactions which later can be used to compile relevant data/reports out of.

My requirements regarding the transactions are:

- Once a transaction is added/posted to the general ledger, in order to ensure a complete audit trail, the transaction cannot be changed or removed.
- A new transaction can only be added if the corresponding date is in a certain (fiscal) period. Other checks (e.g. if credit and debit amounts match) will also be applied.

  - Existing transactions (i.e. earlier posted transaction) should also be available but when loaded they must no longer pass the checks mentioned above (e.g. they might be from a earlier fiscal period).

Here is what I have come up with so far:

```
public class GeneralLedger
{
    public int GeneralLedgerId { get; set; }
    public DateTime FiscalPeriodStartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime FiscalPeriodEndDate { get; set; }
    private ICollection<GeneralLedgerTransaction> _transactions;

    public ICollection<GeneralLedgerTransaction> Transactions {
        get
        {
            if (this._transactions != null) { 
                return this._transactions.ToList().AsReadOnly();
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    public void AddTransaction(GeneralLedgerTransaction trx)
    {
        if (trx.PostingDate < this.FiscalPeriodStartDate || trx.PostingDate > this.FiscalPeriodEndDate)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("invalid booking date");
        }
        else
        {
            this._transactions.Add(trx);
        }
    }

}

public class GeneralLedgerTransaction
{
    public int GeneralLedgerTransactionId { get; set; }
    public DateTime PostingDate { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GeneralLedgerTransactionLine> GeneralLedgerTransactionLines { get; set; }
}

public class GeneralLedgerTransactionLine
{
    public int GeneralLedgerTransactionLineId { get; set; }
    public int FinancialAccountId { get; set; }
    public virtual FinancialAccount FinancialAccount { get; set; }
    public int GeneralLedgerTransactionTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual GeneralLedgerTransactionType GeneralLedgerTransactionType { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}

public class FinancialAccount
{
    public int FinancialAccountId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class GeneralLedgerTransactionType
{
    public int GeneralLedgerTransactionTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<GeneralLedger> GeneralLedgers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<GeneralLedgerTransaction> GeneralLedgerTransactions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<GeneralLedgerTransactionLine> GeneralLedgerTransactionLines { get; set; }
    public DbSet<FinancialAccount> FinancialAccounts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<GeneralLedgerTransactionType> GeneralLedgerTransactionTypes { get; set; }
}
```

Now this works well in terms of no existing transaction can be removed or altered as the the `Transaction` property returns a `ReadOnly`-list and every new newly added transaction is checked against the date period rule. And I also can see that the records are saved to the database. So far so good, the only thing that I am currently missing is that existing records are not loaded to `_transactions`.

What can I do to make existing transactions available in `_transactions` without calling the entity framework from within the domain class? Or is there maybe a better way (i.e. a better design) to solve this problem?

Comment: Put simply, you are wanting to allow for new records to be added (if they meet certain criteria), but existing records should not be able to be modified, correct?

Comment: Well, neither modified nor deleted but other than that, I think that's pretty much it.

Comment: How are you binding the data? Is it being placed into a data grid? Is it on a web page? Windows app?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention it. It will be an ASP.NET MVC app.

Comment: If this is an MVC application, can you not simply remove the edit and delete controllers? Instead, simply leave the details, index, and create controllers. This will allow users to input items into the ledger, but not modify and/or delete them.

Comment: Yes I could do that but I don't think this would be good code design because this requires the person working on the code (and in the future that might be somebody else) to know the rules and _to follow them_. It's like making all properties and methods of your classes public even though some might and should be for internal use only and by making them public you risk people messing with stuff.

Comment: Very true, but if these actions are never going to occur, there's no reason to have controllers or views for them. Not every entity requires full CRUD functionality. On the flip side, you could create an "Audit" object that stores any modifications to any properties or entities. And instead of having a delete controller, you can have a controller that marks a property called `IsDeleted` on your entities. There are many ways of accomplishing this, but you have to decide on a design pattern to do so.

Comment: I totally agree and I don't plan to implement any views/controllers for actions that actually do not exist. Nevertheless I think the desired behavior should be implemented on the class (I assume `GeneralLedger` in my case). I came across the Audit pattern before but I don't think it is the solution here because as far as I understand the Audit pattern helps to track changes within objects. However in my case there are not gonna be any changes. - I agree that it's most likely about picking the right pattern and that is probably what I am struggling with/looking for. But I haven't found it yet.

Comment: Try looking at a repository/functionality model pattern. Essentially you will build a wrapper around your models that handle certain functions (creation, viewing, etc). You abstract away all your functions away from your base model, and handle all interactions through that.[Here is the wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_model)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation I learned that I can achieve what I was looking for as follows:

- changing `_transactions` from `private` to `protected virtual`
- adding `modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new GeneralLedger.GeneralLedgerTransactionsMapper());` to `OnModelCreating`
- creating the following configuration-class:

.

```
public class GeneralLedgerTransactionsMapper : EntityTypeConfiguration<GeneralLedger>
    {
        public GeneralLedgerTransactionsMapper()
        {
            HasMany(s => s._transactions);
        }
    }
```